# regex to remove CR LF unless last character was a period?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to make regex remove CR (carriage returns) and line feed (LF) which are both end of line markers, only if the last alphanumeric character was a period?

I am trying to manually transcribe two-column text from a OCR'ed pdf to single column plain text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `/\.\r\n/` with `'.'`

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are looking to just `s/\.$\r\n/./g`